# Condo Master Policy in case of a Fire

Tags: landlord, insurance

I own a condo that was rented out and had a fire.  The condo association's master policy covers repairs from "sheetrock out".  I'm out of state, but the best I've heard, the fire mainly damaged the inside, no studs or structural items (bricks) were impacted.

1. Since the condo association is the one insured, should they handle the hiring of contractors to gut existing sheetrock, and put up new sheetrock?
2. If fire was primarily in one bedroom, but smoke damage effected whole unit, does that call for removing/replacing of all sheetrock?
3. Would the condo or the owner be responsible for removing damaged furniture, wet carpet, etc...

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. No, it calls for replacing anything that is damaged - smoke and water can damage things that were a long way from the flames but determining if something *was* damaged is subject to agreement (or dispute) between you, the owner’s association and the insurer(s).
3. Fixtures like carpets, furniture, light fittings etc. are your responsibility.

Comment: I know buying new carpet, lights etc... is my responsibility, I was referring to removal of the these items in order to fix the damage.